# -n weak-declension plural

Tags: declension, weak-declension

I am struggling to understand a simple exercise in my textbook.

The task is to complete the ending for two words (italics) in the following sentence:

> *Auszubildende_* und *Angestellte_* verdienen im nächsten Jahr mehr

The answer according to the textbook is that the sentence is correct as it is, without any modification. My guess was that both nouns should be in plural and therefore because of the -n deklination go with an additional -n at the end.

Comment: What remains unclear after looking at [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Angestellte)? It has separate tables for easy comparison...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your assumption that (almost all) nouns ending in unstressed *-e* form the plural with *-n* is correct, *Auszubildend-* and *Angestellt-* are nouns that inflect like adjectives, which do have the **strong ending -e** in the nominative and accusative plural.

> sehr geehrt**e** Damen und Herren
> lieb**e** Freunde
> Auszubildend**e** und Angestellt**e**

The *weak ending* in this instance is *-en*.

> mein**e** sehr geehrt*en* Damen und Herren
> mein**e** lieb*en* Freunde
> all**e** Auszubildend*en* und Angestellt*en*

An example in the singular.

> mein gut**er** Freund
> ein zufrieden**er** Angestellt**er**

> d**er** gut*e* Freund
> d**er** zufrieden*e* Angestellt*e*

Other nouns that inflect like adjectives:

> ein Erwachsener, Jugendlicher, Deutscher, Beamter
> der Erwachsene, Jugendliche, Deutsche, Beamte

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't have an *-n* in the (indefinite) nominative case plural:

> ein Auszubildender, zwei Auszubildende

But they do in the definite:

> der Auszubildende, die Auszubildenden.

Comment: Thank you, but why they don't have an -n? I guess this is my question

Comment: @dapias I'm finding it difficult to find any source for this, as declination tables usually include determiners, which is the distinctive difference here. I guess without the determiner as a case marker it would create an ambiguity with the accusative, where you would add an _-n_.

Comment: I think I have found the general principle under the name of "Substantivierte Adjektive und Partizipien", as it is explained for instance [here](https://deutschlernerblog.de/deutscher-deutsche-oder-deutschen-substantivierte-adjektive). Thanks for the help @OliverMason!